# Odoo - how to use it interactively in python interpreter?

Tags: python, terminal, odoo

I read here that it might be possible to use python interpreter to access Odoo and test things interactively (https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-get-a-python-shell-with-the-odoo-environment-54096), but doing this in terminal:

`ipython`

```
import sys
import openerp
sys.argv = ['', '--addons-path=~/my-path/addons', '--xmlrpc-port=8067', '--log-level=debug', '-d test',]
openerp.cli.main()
```

it starts Odoo server, but I can't write anything in that terminal tab to use it interactively. If for example I write anything like `print 'abc'`, I don't get any output. Am I missing something here?

Comment: In version 10: ./odoo-bin shell -d <database> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293139/how-to-run-odoo-orm-methods-in-the-python-console

Answer (score 0):

Sometime I use *"logging"* library for print output on the console/terminal.

For example:

```
import logging
logging.info('Here is your message')
logging.warning('Here is your message')
```

For more details, You may checkout this [reference link.](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html)

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I have found to interactive is put the line

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

in the method I want to inspect, and then trigger that method.

It's clunky, but it works.

As an example, I was just enhancing the OpenChatter implementation for our copy of OpenERP, and during the "figure things out" stage I had that line in `.../addons/mail/mail_thread.py::mail_thread.post_message` so I could get a better idea of what was happening in that method.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is with shell:

```
./odoo-bin shell -d <yourdatabase>
```

Please, be aware that if you already have an instance of odoo, the port will be busy. In that case, the instance you are opening should be using a different port. So the command should be something like this:

```
./odoo-bin shell --xmlrpc-port=8888 -d <yourdatabase>
```

But if you want to have your addons available in the new instance, yo can make something similar to the following:

```
./odoo-bin shell -c ~/odooshell.conf -d <yourdatabase>
```

This way you can have in your odooshell.conf whatever you need to have configured (port, addons_path, etc). This way you can work smoothly with your shell.

As I always use docker, this is what I do to have my shell configured in docker:

```
docker exec -ti <mycontainer> odoo shell -c /etc/odoo/odooshell.conf -d <mydatabase>
```

You will have the env available to do anything. You can create express python code to make whatever you need. The syntax is very similar to server actions. For example:

```
partner_ids = env['res.partner'].search([])
for partner in partner_ids:
    partner['name'] = partner.name + '.'
env.cr.commit()
```

Remember to `env.cr.commit()` if you make any data change.