# How to run Odoo ORM methods in the python console?

Tags: python, shell, import, odoo

I would like to use ORM methods such as `browse` or `search` in the python console.

```
$pwd
/opt/odoo/

$python
>>> import openerp
>>> product_obj = pool.get('product.product)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pool' is not defined
```

How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In version 9 you can start an odoo shell with `odoo.py shell -d <database>`, thanks to [this commit](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/9ed13353c0d5f6b8a9684e612514b3b834642554)

In version 8 the functionality is not builtin but you can use [this script](https://gist.github.com/dreispt/d14e424540faedb3ea88), [this module](https://apps.openerp.com/apps/modules/8.0/shell/), or [OERPLib](https://pythonhosted.org/OERPLib/)

Comment: In version 10: ./odoo-bin shell -d <database>

Comment: `shell` **must** be the first argument !

Answer (score 0):

Pool needs to be connected with a database, so you need to instantiate a pool first, for exemple:

```
pool = openerp.modules.registry.RegistryManager.get("test")
```

This should return a pool connected to the 'test' database